# Rails active record querying nested association existence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have simple model of `Product`, `Guide` and `Document` which are like this :

`Product` has many `Guides` and `Guide` has many `Documents`

The query I'm looking for is to return the Product only if it contains a document.

`Product.joins(:guides).distinct` is giving Product with at least a guide, but how to add a nested level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Product.joins(guides: :documents).distinct
```

Assuming your models have set up the `has_many` associations, your table names are standard, and that should generate the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "products".* FROM "products"
INNER JOIN "guides" ON "guides"."product_id" = "products"."id"
INNER JOIN "documents" ON "documents"."guides_id" = "guides"."id"
```

(The query will vary based on the flavor of SQL you are using; This is for Postgres.)